# How do I modify the background color of a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to recreate an UI I built with UIKit in SwiftUI but I'm running into some minor issues.

I want the change the color of the `List` here, but no property seems to work as I expects. Sample code below:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var listData: ListData

       var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(listData.items) { item in
                ListItemCell(item: item)
            }
            .content.background(Color.yellow) // not sure what content is defined as here
            .background(Image("paper-3")) // this is the entire screen 
        }
    }
}

struct ListItemCell: View {
    let item: ListItem

    var body: some View {

        NavigationButton(destination: Text(item.name)) {
            Text("\(item.name) ........................................................................................................................................................................................................")
                .background(Color.red) // not the area I'm looking for
        }.background(Color.blue) // also not the area I'm looking for
    }
}
```

[image: I want to change the WHITE area]

Comment: [This worked for me. Adding it to my ContentView_Previews. When you use a List just make sure what ever stack you have at the top has a spacer in it at the top. The .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) likes to misbehave.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF4Sf.png)

Comment: With the help of another answer I was able to color every single element of the list in a different way, like in your screenshot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514684/9439097

Comment: For any future viewers, here's the **iOS 16** version https://stackoverflow.com/a/72650158/13278922

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution for coloring the list rows:

```
struct TestRow: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a row!")
        .listRowBackground(Color.green)
    }
}
```

and then in body:

```
List {
    TestRow()
    TestRow()
    TestRow()
}
```

This works as I expect, but I have yet to find out how to then remove the dividing lines between the rows...

Comment: SwiftUI is incredibly buggy right now, this works when I use this code like this and hard code my list items. When I load my data async it does not work anymore..

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a pain. Fun to play with, though. Should be more smoothed out soon, hopefully

Comment: @MariusWaldal Did you find how to change section view background color?

Comment: @andromedainiative Do List { ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in Text(item).listRowBackground(Color.green) } instead, then it works.

Comment: I had this really stupid issue where the .listRowBackground() modifier HAD to be after the .contextMenu() modifier, otherwise it wouldn't work. Xcode 12.0.1

Comment: changing the listRowBackground results in losing the selection brief color change when you tap on a navigationLink.  That gray highlight that appears briefly when you press a row in a list to push to another view.  I can't figure out how to get that back or replicate it.

Comment: This removes the color change when the row is selected. Do you know how to keep it?

Answer (score 54):

This will set the background of the whole list to green:

```
init() {
   UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
   UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
   UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
}
```

Comment: How would I vary this across different lists? I applied this to one list in one tab, and this affected the other list in another tab view.

Comment: Nice, also can use: 
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .darkGray

Comment: @glothais-kwl did you find a way to "reset" the TableView appearances!? Like you I would like this on certain views and not on all of them and need a way to reset it based on view displayed.

Comment: It's angering that such an important change (because otherwise your list will be floating over a white background) is so out of context to access.
Can also be used like:

            List {
            }.onAppear{
                UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
                UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
            }

Comment: @glothais-kwl you can use `UIAppearance.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:` and pass there a specific subclass of `UIHostingController` that you will use to present this exact SwiftUI view.

Comment: This also fails to work on items that are nested lists using List(_,children:). The background is hardwired to black on these, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 50):

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var strings = ["a", "b"]

    var body: some View {

        List {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(string)
            }.listRowBackground(Color.green)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but I am still stuck at figuring out how to change the background of the List itself.

Comment: This is the only one that works for me as well. I think it's important to emphasise that you have to have `List { ForEach(elements) { }}` as opposed to `List(elements) { }` in order for this modifier to work.

Comment: Insane that the WAY that you specify the data to the list makes this modifier not work. Doesn't leave good view on SwiftUI as a whole seeing this kind of bugs within it.

Comment: This is fixed in iOS 15. `listRowBackground` works with items within `List(elements)` as well as `List { ForEach(elements) {`

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov you can change the background of the list if the list style is .plain.

Comment: This removes the color change when the row is selected. Do you know how to keep it?

Answer (score 43):

iOS 16 provides a modifier to control the background visibility of List (and other scrollable views): [scrollContentBackground(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/scrollcontentbackground(_:))

You can hide the standard system background via `.hidden`. If you provide a `background` as well, that will become visible.

```
List {
    Text("One")
    Text("Two")
}
.background(Image("MyImage"))
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

You may also want to customize the background of list rows - the individual cells - and separators. This can be done like so:

```
List {
    Section("Header") {
        Text("One")
        Text("Two")
            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 33):

You can do it by changing `UITableView`'s appearance.

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

just put this line in `Appdelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. 
In replace of `UIColor.clear` set whatever color you want to add in background color of `list`.

Comment: It works but it doesn't remove white background under rows that are actually displayed

Comment: It do the job: UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear

Comment: Is there a solution for Mac for this?

Comment: @davidev my answer below

Comment: The question was "How do I modify the background color of a List in SwiftUI?" why are you talking about UITableView.appearance() and AppleDelegate ? :-/ Please read carefully the questions..

Answer (score 25):

**Changing Background Color**

As other have mentioned, changing the UITableView background will affect all other lists in your app.

However if you want different background colors you can set the default to **clear**, and set the background color in swiftui views like so:

```
List {
    Text("Item 1")
    Text("Item 2")
    Text("Item 3")
}
// Ignore safe area to take up whole screen
.background(Color.purple.ignoresSafeArea())
.onAppear {
    // Set the default to clear
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

You probably want to set the tableview appearance earlier, such as in the **SceneDelegate** or root view like so:

```
// SceneDelegate
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
      
    
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
        print("Returning because screne does not exist")
        return
            
    }
    
    // Set here    
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    let contentView = ContentView()
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}


// Root App View
@main
struct ListBackgroundApp: App {
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Working Background Color Change]

Comment: The trick of setting the backgroundColor to clear, lets you even usage Images as backgrounds! Thank you so much

Answer (score 18):

## 2022

## MacOS Solution

The following code makes ALL OF `List`s background color transparent:

```
// Removes background from List in SwiftUI
extension NSTableView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
        
        backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        if let esv = enclosingScrollView {
            esv.drawsBackground = false
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

..........

..........

..........

the following code makes ALL OF `TextEditor`s background color transparent:

```
extension NSTextView {
    open override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = .clear
            drawsBackground = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! SwiftUI should make this default lol

Comment: holy God, you can override in extension?

Comment: @PeterLapisu as you see you can :) hehehe

Answer (score 16):

There is an argument: listRowBackground() in SwiftUI, but if you use List directly to iterate the data collection, it doesn't work.

Here is my workaround:

```
    List {
        // To make the background transparent, we have we use a ForEach as a wrapper
        ForEach(files) {file in
            Label(
                title: { Text(file.name ?? fileOptionalFiller).lineLimit(listRowTextLineLimit) },
                icon: { AppIcon.doc.foregroundColor(.primary) }
            )
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.primary.colorInvert())
    }
```

Basically, listRowBackground() works if you use a ForEach inside List.

Comment: The trouble with ForEach is that you can't use collapsible nested lists AFAICT. On my phone (iOS 17.0.2) the background colour of a nested list item is hardwired to black. Not even .listRowBackground changes it. I can't get the background of the item's Text body to expand to fill the entire row, which seems to have some (also hardwired) padding.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with list style grouped.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to get the whole list to change color by using colorMultiply(Color:). Just add this modifier to the end of the list view, and then the padding will push the table to the device edges. For example:

```
List {...}.colorMultiply(Color.green).padding(.top)
```

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-adjust-views-by-tinting-and-desaturating-and-more

Comment: It works, but it messes with the color of the cells - i.e. just tried with red Text as list items - they turn black.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, blending is not what you want. You want it to be layered, with the background view color as, well, background, and then the cell color and/or text color to be on top of that

Answer (score 11):

I do not know what is the connection but if you wrap the list with `Form` it is working.

```
Form {
     List(viewModel.currencyList, id: \.self) { currency in
        ItemView(item: currency)
     }
      .listRowBackground(Color("Primary"))
      .background(Color("Primary"))
}
```

Comment: As Caleb points out the listRowBackground shouldn't be applied to the List but to the row item itself.

Also you should be able to just do Color("Primary") instead of force unwrapping a UIColor :)

Comment: This works, but then, I have a section header in the list and that header is now not `sticky`-- it moves with the list :(.

Answer (score 7):

```
struct Details: View {

    var body: some View {
        Spacer().overlay(
            List {
                Text("Hello World!").font(.title2)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                Text("Hello World again").font(.title2)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }.onAppear() {
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer by Islom Alimov https://stackoverflow.com/a/59970379/9439097 seems to be the best implementation so far in my opinion.

**Only drawback:** this also changes the background color of all other list views in your app, so you need to manually change them back unless you want the same color everywhere.

Here is an example view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView1: View {
    
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.clear)
    }
    
    @State var data = ["abc", "def"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) {element in
                    Text("\(String(describing: element))")
                }
                .background(Color.green)
                .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
                
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
            Spacer()
            Color.red
        }
    }
}

struct TestView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView1()
    }
}
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Someone may find this useful if attempting to create a floating type cell with SwiftUI using `.listRowBackground` and applying `.padding`

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach (site) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(String(item.id))

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.name)
                        Text(item.crop[0])
                    }

                }.listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
                      .padding(.trailing, 5)
                      .padding(.leading, 5)
                      .padding(.top, 2)
                      .padding(.bottom, 2))
            }
        }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Locations"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @caleb81389, It's working for me but it will not apply to empty rows. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: No sorry. I have no idea how to apply that to empty rows. Maybe you could artificially put white space text “ “ in a label or something...? Other than that SwiftUI kinda does what it wants to and something like that is gonna take someone spatter than me to answer.

Comment: Let me know if you figure it out!

Answer (score 6):

```
List {
         ForEach(dataArray, id:\.self) { item in
             Text("\(item)")
                 .font(.title3)
         }
         .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)) // EdgeInsets
         .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // Change Row Color
         .listRowSeparator(.hidden) //hide Seprator
     }
     .listStyle(.plain) //Change ListStyle
     .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
     .background(Color.yellow) //Change Background Color
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume the [`listRowPlatterColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278590-listrowplattercolor) modifier should do this, but isn't as of Xcode 11 Beta 11M336w

```
var body: some View {
    List(pokemon) { pokemon in
        PokemonCell(pokemon: pokemon)
            .listRowPlatterColor(.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: `listRowPlatterColor` is now deprecated and workend only on watchOS.

Answer (score 3):

### .colorMultiply(...)

As an option you can `.colorMultiply(Color.yourColor)` modifier.

**Warning**: **this does not change the color!** This only applies the `Multiply` modifier to the current color. Please read the question before any action, because you are probably looking for: "How to **CHANGE** the background color of a List in SwiftUI" and this will not work for you. ❄️

**Example:**

```
List (elements, id:\.self ) { element in

     Text(element)

}
.colorMultiply(Color.red) <--------- replace with your color
```

[image]

Comment: works well, however if user switches to dark mode it fails miserably. I expect this is SwiftUI bug

Comment: this just overlays a cooler and multiply, it doesn't change current color

Comment: @ManeManero I wonder if you read the question of the post: "How do I modify the background color of a List in SwiftUI?" This does not change the color, it modifies it. And for dark mode, yup, you need to add more logic/conditions for specific changes.

Comment: This will mess up with the row background color

Comment: does not work properly with dark theme, this solution is useless.

Comment: Simple solution if your only changing the color to debug your layout.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason color change is not working, you can try the .listStyle to .plain

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Test")

        List {
            ForEach(1 ..< 4) { items in
                Text(String(items))
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In iOS 16**, we got a native way to do this via [scrollcontentbackground](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-list-background-color/) modifier.

You can either **change the color** by setting a color (`ShapeStyle`) to `scrollcontentbackground`.

```
List {
    Text("Item 1")
    Text("Item 2")
    Text("Item 3")
}
.scrollContentBackground(Color.pink)
```

Or you can **hide the background** `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` and set a custom one with `.backgroud` modifier.

```
List {
    Text("Item 1")
    Text("Item 2")
    Text("Item 3")
}
.background {
    Image("ventura")

}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Comment: Even though the [iPadOS 16 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ipados-16-release-notes) say that `.scrollContentBackground` "permits customisation of background colours for scrollable views like List" it is still currently limited to `Visibility` according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/scrollcontentbackground%28_:%29). Perhaps that will change when iPadOS 16 is released.

Answer (score 2):

For me, a perfect solution to change the background of List in SwiftUI is:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    init(){
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundLight")
      }
...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

List is not perfect yet.

An option would be to use it like this -> `List { ForEach(elements) { }}` instead of `List($elements)`

On my end this is what worked best up to now.
Like @FontFamily said, it shouldn't break any `List` default behaviors like swiping.

Comment: This kills the functionality of onDelete and onMove for nested list items.

Comment: Does it kill it for the second example I gave? I think with the `List { ForEach(elements) }` it should be fine right?

Comment: You are right - it does work for the second example you gave.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Add `UITableView` appearance background color in `init()` method and add list style `(.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())`. Don't forget to import `UIKit` module

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

let tempData:[TempData] = [TempData( name: "abc"),
                         TempData( name: "abc"),
                         TempData( name: "abc"),
                         TempData( name: "abc")]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("loginBackgound")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
        List{
            ForEach(tempData){ data in
                Text(data.name)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing background did not work for me, because of the system background. I needed to hide it.

```
List(examples) { example in
        ExampleRow(example: example)
    }.background(Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 2):

2024 answer, they seem to change the List implementation often. In fact, it used to use a TableView now it uses a CollectionView. `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` is what made it work for me.

```
List {
  ...
}
.modifier(ListBackgroundModifier())
```

```
struct ListBackgroundModifier: ViewModifier {

    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .background(Color(UIColor.background).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

OR if using `.listStyle(InsetListStyle())` you can just do this on each item in the list: `.listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.background).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))`

Answer (score 1):

Using *UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor* is **not a good** idea as it changes the backgroundColor of all tables. I found a working solution for color changing at the exact table you selected in **iOS 14, 15**.

We will change the color using a modifier that needs to be applied inside the List

```
extension View {
    
    func backgroundTableModifier(_ color: UIColor? = nil) -> some View {
        self.modifier(BackgroundTableModifier(color: color))
    }

}
```

Our task is to find the UITableView and after that change the color.

```
private struct BackgroundTableModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    private let color: UIColor?
    @State private var tableView: UITableView?
    
    init(color: UIColor?) {
        self.color = color
    }
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if tableView?.backgroundColor != color {
            content
                .overlay(BackgroundTableViewRepresentable(tableBlock: { tableView in
                    tableView.backgroundColor = color
                    self.tableView = tableView
                }))
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}

private struct BackgroundTableViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var tableBlock: (UITableView) -> ()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> BackgroundTableView  {
        let view = BackgroundTableView(tableBlock: tableBlock)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: BackgroundTableView, context: Context) {}
}

class BackgroundTableView: UIView {
    
    var tableBlock: (UITableView) -> ()
    
    init(tableBlock: @escaping (UITableView) -> ()) {
        self.tableBlock = tableBlock
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let tableView = findTableView(in: self) {
            tableBlock(tableView)
        }
    }
    
    private func findTableView(in view: UIView) -> UITableView? {
        if let tableView = view as? UITableView {
            return tableView
        }
        
        if let superView = view.superview {
            return findTableView(in: superView)
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

In order to find UITableView, the modifier must be inside the List. Naturally, you need to ensure that the modifier is called only once, you do not need to apply it to each row. Here is an example of usage

```
List {
   rows()
     .backgroundTableModifier(.clear)
}

func rows() -> some View {
    ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
        Row()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! this works perfectly and solves the issue of colouring all the tableViews in the app !

Answer (score 1):

[Before and After modifiers applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eSmG.png)

iOS 16

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("Sample text")
                } //: LOOP
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            } //: LIST
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } //: ZSTACK
        .background(
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've inspired some of the configurator used to config per page NavigationView nav bar style and write some simple UITableView per page configurator not use UITableView.appearance() global approach

```
   import SwiftUI

    struct TableViewConfigurator: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

        var configure: (UITableView) -> Void = { _ in }

        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TableViewConfigurator>) -> UIViewController {

            UIViewController()
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TableViewConfigurator>) {

            let tableViews = uiViewController.navigationController?.topViewController?.view.subviews(ofType: UITableView.self) ?? [UITableView]()

            for tableView in tableViews {
                self.configure(tableView)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then there is UIView extension needed to find all UITableViews

```
extension UIView {
    func subviews<T:UIView>(ofType WhatType:T.Type) -> [T] {
        var result = self.subviews.compactMap {$0 as? T}
        for sub in self.subviews {
            result.append(contentsOf: sub.subviews(ofType:WhatType))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

And usage at the end is:

```
List {

}.background(TableViewConfigurator {
    $0.backgroundColor = .red
})
```

Maybe one thing should be improved that is usage of navigationController?.topViewController to make it work even without navigationController in view controllers hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came here looking for solutions for background in landscape not full width on iPhone X/11 try:

```
.listRowBackground(Color("backgroundColour").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid setting the appearance for all table views globally, you can combine `UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:)` with `UIHostingController`. Thanks [DanSkeel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991816/danskeel) for the comment you left above pointing this out. This is how I used it:

```
public class ClearTableViewHostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View {
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [ClearTableViewHostingController<Content>.self]).backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

You can use `ClearTableViewHostingController` like this:

```
let view = MyListView()
let viewController = ClearTableViewHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: view)
```

Then in your view you can set the list background color like so:

```
List {
    Text("Hello World")
}
.background(Color.gray)
```

Comment: This is the best solution that I found with a slight change. Instead of using wrapper class, I set appearance in view's init
 init() {
        UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIHostingController<MyView>.self]).backgroundColor = .color
}

Answer (score 0):

Make extension List like:

```
extension List{
@available(iOS 14, *)
func backgroundList(_ color: Color = .clear) -> some View{
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(color)
    return self
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use `introspect` library from Github to set the background color for the underlying table view like this:

```
List { ... } .introspectTableView { tableView in
                tableView.backgroundColor = .yellow
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func blurredSheet<Content: View>(_ style: AnyShapeStyle, isPresented: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss: @escaping ()->(), @ViewBuilder content: @escaping ()->Content) -> some View {
        self
            .sheet(isPresented: isPresented, onDismiss: onDismiss) {
                content()
                    .background(RemoveBackgroundColor())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(style)
                            .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .all)
                    }
            }
    }
}

fileprivate struct RemoveBackgroundColor: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 15 or earlier, doing this once

```
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

makes the .background view modifier work on any list after that. So in my app I just do

```
@main
struct MyApp: App
{
    init()
    {
        // Work around SwiftUI's ridiculous lack of a way to set a list view's background color.
        // Oddly, this will enable the .background view modifier to work on lists from now on.
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
...
}
```

After that, in any SwiftUI view you can do:

```
List(msgs) { aMsg in
        Text(aMsg.senderID)
}
.background(Color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Gradient(colors: [.white, Color.init(uiColor: .mainBackground)]))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        List {      ...      }
            .background(.clear)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

Xcode Version 12.4

The **Background** property worked for me, but with the mandatory use of **Opacity**.
Without **opacity** it is not work.

```
List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.id) { (item) in
                ListRow(item)
                    .environmentObject(self.data)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .opacity(0.5)
```

Comment: while this does work, it also makes the list transparent. I tried ```opacity(0.5)```, ```opacity(1)```, ```opacity(0)``` and none gave a result where the list rows where present and the list background the desired color

Comment: This is an irrelevant answer, which also won't work.