# Having Problems Setting View Background Color with List View--SwiftUI

Tags: list, background, swiftui, zstack

[image]I want to set the View Background color to green. I have a List View and it's fine but the underlying view needs to be green--see image. I know I'm missing something but with SwiftUI you sometimes don't know if it's a bug or just how the thing is supposed to work. Any ideas that have worked for others I would appreciate. I have attached my code and I am on Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c).

Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
     ZStack() {
          Color(red: 95.0/255.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 128.0/255)
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

          Text("")
          List {
              Group {
                  Text("Price: ")
                  Text("Down: ")
                  Text("APR: ")
                  Text("Term: ")
                  Text("Tax: ")
                  Text("Rebate: ")
              }.listRowBackground(Color(red: 95.0/255.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 128.0/255))

              Group {
                  Text("Add On: ")
                  Text("Fees: ")
                  Text("Trade Value: ")
                  Text("Total Interest: ")
                  Text("Payment: ")
              }.listRowBackground(Color(red: 95.0/255.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 128.0/255))
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: refer to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517904/how-do-i-modify-the-background-color-of-a-list-in-swiftui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `swiftui` doesn't support this yet, however, `List` is just a `uitableview` under the hood so you can just change the `UITableView` properties.

```
struct StackOverflow1: View {
   // you need to modify the UItableview in the initializer
   init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .yellow       // Change background color
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green    // Change each cell's background color
   }

    var body: some View {
       // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Its important to note that this will change all `List` instances in this view so if you have multiple Lists they all will be the same colors.

to overcome this issue you can make different views for each List and then embed them in your main view.

Comment: This works, and thanks. The  "UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .yellow" code I will have to customize but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It shouldn’t be very different from what you did, it’s straight forward, if you have any troubles please let me know.

Comment: Great! Good luck.

Comment: what if I want to set an image to a background? @Muhand Jumah

Comment: @MertKöksal you could set color to clear and put your Image and List in a Zstack

Comment: Can you demonstrate it simply?

Comment: Here, i wrote a quick gist. https://gist.github.com/Muhand/d78d1c81bd9fef507caee0b966dfe4c0

Comment: @MertKöksal forgot to mention you in the previous comment. I hope you saw it.