# iOS 16 SwiftUI List Background

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, ios16

With the new `SwiftUI` update in iOS 16 `List` no longer depends on `UITableView`. So the following snippet we used to set the `List` background color to `.clear` is now useless:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

I saw that someone used `introspect` to solve the problem, but does anyone know of another maybe cleaner way to achieve the same behavior?

Also note that on `macOS`, the following works fine (Tested using `Xcode 14 beta` & `macOS Ventura`):

```
extension NSTableView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
        backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        enclosingScrollView!.drawsBackground = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

iOS 16 adds a new modifier, [scrollContentBackground(Visibility)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/scrollcontentbackground(_:)), to customize the background visibility for scrollable views including `List`.

You can hide the standard system background like so which will reveal the List's background if you provide one:

```
List {
    Text("One")
    Text("Two")
    Text("Three")
}
.background(Image("MyImage"))
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Comment: I'm using beta 4 and passing it a color like `.red` instead of `.hidden` gives "Cannot convert value of type 'Color' to expected argument type 'Visibility'".

Comment: @MarkVolkmann oh interesting, it seems they’ve removed the ability to use a Color in beta 4

Comment: Thank you. Finally something works in 2023!!

Comment: This was the only correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 37):

#### iOS 16

#### Update: Xcode 14b3+

Just use new modifier:

```
    List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
    .scrollContentBackground(Color.red)     // << here !!
//    .scrollContentBackground(Color.clear)     // << transparent !!
//    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)     // << can be combined with above !!
```

#### Original

Now they use `UICollectionView` for backend, so an updated workaround is to change corresponding background colors:

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
extension UICollectionReusableView {
    override open var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get { .clear }
        set { }

        // default separators use same color as background
        // so to have it same but new (say red) it can be
        // used as below, otherwise we just need custom separators
        // 
        // set { super.backgroundColor = .red }

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UICollectionView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
//...
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/iOS16/TestListBackgroundiOS16.swift)

Comment: This was a great help, although when I override the `backgroundColor` getter, I lose my `listRowSeparatorTint` (As can be seen in your image). Any idea how to get it back?

Comment: @Darren, see updated in comments

Comment: Thank you. That's a shame it uses the same as background. When you say about custom separators, do you mean adding an actual line to each row's view?

Comment: Yes, they do the same, actually even worse, because adding SwiftUI line just adds drawing line to context, but Apple adds new UIView for each separator line.

Comment: The new `.scrollContentBackground` in beta 3 makes everything work as expected without this workaround and different color separators.

Comment: I think the new beta doesn't allow `scrollContentBackground` to be used directly with `Style`. It should be set to `.hidden` and then composed with `.background(style)`.

Comment: Asperi coming with the fire again!  At the time of my post, no where does anyone else say to use UICollectionView.  All suggestions say to use UITableView.  I get that they changed it, but for folks like me who need to use a List, because of the .refreshable modifier, and still need to support 15, this is the top answer currently.  Thank you Asperi!

Comment: Works for iOS16, but how can i fix iOS14? `extension UICollectionReusableView` would also override other usages which is a problem in older, large projects

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Color' to expected argument type 'Visibility'

Comment: `scrollContentBackground` API only supports visibility, not color in latest XCode (14.3.1), and even that is not respected by the `List` if it's style is `.plain`. It ignores both the `.scrollContentBackground` and the `.background`

Comment: this answer is no longer valid

Answer (score 29):

For that purpose, I created a custom identifier that hides this custom scroll background.

```
struct ListBackgroundModifier: ViewModifier {

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List {
    ...
}
.modifier(ListBackgroundModifier())
```

Comment: Yes, if you want it to have the same style all over the app. It wasn't the case in mine.

Comment: I noticed another bug, when the list is empty, it will ignore this modifier. In that case just place a thin 1 pixel Color line like this (replace color with your background):

Color.red.frame(height: 1).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                        .listRowSeparatorTint(.clear)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.red)

And call on List: .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 1). Beware: preview will work without this fix, just not on the device/simulator.

Comment: Yes thanks its very good idea to custom create a modifier work for me

Answer (score 10):

As of Xcode **15.1**, the working code is

```
List {
    Text("1")
    Text("2")
    Text("3")
}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background(.purple)
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. I'm struggling to understand why they make it so hard to change the color of a list?