# SwiftUI - How to set List background to clear?

Tags: ios, swiftui, colors, beta, xcode14

In SwiftUI it appears there are two options for modifying colors to a list.

1. Set a list's row background color

   ```
   List {        
     ForEach(elements, id:\.self) { element in
     }.listRowBackground(Color.blue)
   }
   ```
2. Set a list's color scheme to either 'light' or 'dark'

   ```
    List {        
      ForEach(elements, id:\.self) { element in
      }
    }.colorScheme(.light) // .dark
   ```

Setting other attributes like background, foreground color, etc... seems to have zero effect on the view color of interest.

At the moment I do have the List embedded in a Navigation View as such:

```
NavigationView {
  List {        
    ForEach(elements, id:\.self) { element in
    }
  }.colorScheme(.light) // .dark
}
```

But again, no color settings or view hierarchy setup seem to enable to ability to set the background view to clear/transparent so the color of the main view can be the driver. Rather it appears from experimentation that we are forced to choose either a white or black background. Is this a swift or Xcode bug or are there any solutions available?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72650158/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Although there wasn't an accepted answer on there, it did lead me in the correct direction

Comment: .listRowBackground(Color.clear) is working to clear the background.

Answer (score 20):

In order to set a List View Background Color one must set the `scrollContentBackground` attribute to hidden and the `background` attribute to a color

```
List {
  ForEach(elements, id:\.self) { element in 
  }.listRowBackground(Color.white)
}.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
 .background(Color.blue)
```

[image]

Comment: I’ve been looking for this answer for days. Thank you.