# SwiftUI - background colour of the Section is not applied to entire section

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

First of all playground example that demonstrates the problem:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MyList: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
    
    private var content: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("hello")
            }
            .background(Color.red) // This only changes small area around text. Looking for Workaround 2
        }
        .background(Color.blue) // This doesn't work (Workaround 1)
        .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
    }
    
    init() {
        
        // Workaround 1 - works
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
        
        // Workaround 2 - nothing below helps
        UITableView.appearance().sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = .green
        UITableView.appearance().sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .green
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundView = nil
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundConfiguration = .clear()
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MyList())

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Explanation:

- `View` has a `List`, which I need to change background for. There's a well-known workaround to change it via `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor`, which is what I do. So far so good.
- I also need to change the background of the section. In the image below I want the entire section to be **red**, not white. White should not exist at all:

[image]

But I can't find the way to achieve this. If I add `.background(Color.red)` to the Section, it only changes the small area around the text. OK, but if the white area is not part of `List`, and not `Section` then what is the rest of the white area?

I tried various workarounds found in SO, as listed under `// Workaround 2 - nothing below helps`. None of them help.

So my question is, simply put, how do I get rid of white area in this layout.

Note:

- I would prefer to not switch away from List, unless it's the only option.
- Answers involving introspect are fine too.

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517904/how-do-i-modify-the-background-color-of-a-list-in-swiftui) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
.background(Color.red) // This only changes small area around text. Looking for Workaround 2
```

To:

```
.listRowBackground(Color.red)
```

[Apple Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/listrowbackground(_:))

[image: Red Background]

Comment: great, thanks, can't believe I missed it