# Unable to change List background in newest SwiftUI?

Tags: uitableview, swiftui

I wanna remove the bakcground of the default list.
All of these solution didn't work, it's there any new modifier we can use to remove bakcground color?

I‘ve tried

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .background(Color.red)
```

and

```
 UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
                UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

The structure is like this

```
VStack{
            Text("My Task")
                .font(.title3).bold()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            List{
                ForEach(realmManager.task, id: \.id){
                    TaskViewItem(task: $0.title, complete: $0.complete).listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
            } .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.972))
```

the TaskViewItem class

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20){
            Image(systemName: !complete ? "circle" : "circle.fill")
            Text(task)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Is your `List` inside a `Form`? is it using a `ForEach` loop? these
 could affect the possible answers. Also have a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517904/how-do-i-modify-the-background-color-of-a-list-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, using a combination of `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` and `.listRowBackground()`
to remove the bakcground of a `List`

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     let names = ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
     
     var body: some View {
         ZStack {
             // for testing, yellow background
             Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
             List (names, id: \.self) { name in
                 Text(name)
                     .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // <-- here
             }
              .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // <-- here
         }
     }
 }
```

EDIT-1:

to show it also work with a custom view `TaskViewItem(...)`

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Task")
                .font(.title3).bold()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) {
                    TaskViewItem(name: $0).listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
            }.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
        .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.972))
    }
}

struct TaskViewItem: View {
    @State var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}
```

EDIT-2:

code with simulated `ForEach(realmManager.task, id: \.id) { task in ...}`. Note the important closure parameter `task in ...`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let tasks = [MyTask(title: "task-1", complete: false),
                 MyTask(title: "task-2", complete: true),
                 MyTask(title: "task-3", complete: false)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Task")
                .font(.title3).bold()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            List {
                ForEach(tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                    TaskViewItem(task: task.title, complete: task.complete)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.pink)  // <-- for testing
      // .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.972))
    }
}

struct TaskViewItem: View {
    let task: String
    let complete: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20){
            Image(systemName: !complete ? "circle" : "circle.fill")
            Text(task)
        }
    }
}

struct MyTask: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var complete: Bool
}
```

Comment: this work on your cases, thanks, but somehow it doesn't work on my cases, which is a List with a custom view

Comment: updated my answer to show it also works with a custom view in the list.

Comment: Still white, but thanks your solution

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution, `EDIT-2`